# I am unable to import an android project in android studio from git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing

I tried doing this but it does not create any gradle file and Manifest.

Comment: What exactly did you try? I can see the Manifest file in your github

Comment: I went to new project tab and made an import for the same. @Vucko

Comment: Well, what is the exact problem? Did u try the answer given below?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that is to use git outside of android studio:
just clone the repository to your computer then in android studio use "open an existing Android studio project" this should create the gradle files for you.

Hope that helped you.